# How to show that $A$ is not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-transformations, diagonalization

We define $A:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ as a linear operator such that $A\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}3x-2y+2z\\4x-4y+6z\\2x-3y+5z\end{bmatrix}$ where, $B$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$$B=\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\6\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}-3\\-5\\6\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}3\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}
\right\}$$

I am guessing that we find $[A]_B^B$ and prove that it is not diagonalizable. How does one prove such claims?

Comment: To show something is not diagonalizable, the first thing you should try is checking if the characteristic polynomial factors over the field you're working in. If it does, you'll want to start looking for deficient eigenspaces.

Comment: Is it sufficient to say that if $A= \begin{bmatrix}3 & -2 & 2\\4 &-4 &6\\2& 3 & 5\end{bmatrix}$ is a diagonalizable matrix then $[A]_B^B$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to say. The matrix of $A$ will be diagonalizable in one basis if and only if it's diagonalizable in any other basis.